# Is it possible to modify the original collection in foreach inside loop?

Tags: mule

I want to mimick this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.getTotal(); i++) {
   // ....
   items = // new items get assigned.
}
```

Is it possible with `foreach` component?

Comment: I don't think `foreach` will work. From my understanding, `foreach` uses iterator so altering the content of list will throw an exception... It would be hard to implement what you want, but you could try having a private flow that has a choice component at the end, one condition/path calls itself (loop) and the otherwise path just exits (loop ends). Then just add the necessary index initialization, index incrementing and alter of list inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will better of using a collection-splitter and a collection-aggregator which will modify the original payload.

```
<collection-splitter />

<set-payload value="do something" />

<collection-aggregator />
```

Alternatively, if you must use foreach, you could use a flowVar to keep track of the items and the set the payload to the flowVar after the foreach:

```
<set-variable variableName="items" value="#[[]]" />

<foreach>
  <set-payload value="do something" />
  <expression-component>flowVars.items.add(payload)</expression-component>
</foreach>

<set-payload value="#[flowVars.items]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:
Outside the foreach:

- Set a session variable X to the content of the linkedlist thru which
  you want to loop.
- All my MS JDBC 4.1 stored procedure calls return 1-n hashmaps with key=resultSetx and value of a linkedlist. Each occurrence in the linkedlist is another hashmap containing a 1 row's worth of resultset pairs (key=value) - so we run into this a lot.

At the foreach top level:

- Set the payload collection reference to the payload which contains
  the linkedlist. 
   Reminder: (The default counter flowVar starts
  at 1. Linkedlist offsets begin at 0.)

Inside the foreach:

- Set another variable (ctr-1) equal to counter - 1; if you don't it
  can make some ugly and difficult MEL with those counter -1
  references).
- Point your list inserts at the session variable X    linkedlist.

After completion of foreach: 
 - Don't forget to remove the redundant list it wastes space.

Cheers-MPC:-)

Comment: so how do you make sure it iterates to the end of the linked list if the length of it during iteration increases?